# Mysql containter data persistance, dockerfile doubts

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm using this docker-compose script to bring up 2 containers, one of which is a Mysql instance.

I'm new to it so I'm sorry if this may sound dumb but I'm sure I'm making some mistake here.

This is my compose file, I've seen other post and it seems like this is the way to mount a volume.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3002:3306
    expose:
      - '3306'

    volumes:
      - "c:/dockerData/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxx
```

I'm testing everything on my laptop, whenever I reboot docker or I send a docker-compose down (ad up again) the tables disappear and I only find a Database with nothing on it. all the tables are currently stored in the volume's host folder but not used anymore by the database.

Everything I do in the other container (nodered with the same persistence) works 
 just fine and every modification is stored correctly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `c:/dockerData/mysql` and see if the files are correctly generated there when the container is up.

If the data files disappear only when the container is started the next time, that would mean that you have a startup script that is deleting / creating the DB upon startup.

Comment: Data is present in the folder but each time I turn off and on my pc or down-up the compose swarm, it seems like the database has been created new from scratch, showing the database but not the tables (which are saved in the structure database/table.ibd)

Comment: I tested it locally on a linux server and it worked normally, first time you start it you'd see "mysql | Initializing database" in the logs, but not in any of the subsequent restarts, which I think is not your case.  So I assume this has to do with Windows Volume mounting, try to change your volume lines to:
    volumes:
    - C:\dockerData\mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw